# The serializer always return none. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

The serializer always return none. Why?? Creating custom models time?

#### File *views.py*

*print* **password = None**

```
class UserLoginView(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data,)
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
email = serializer.data.get('email')
password = serializer.data.get('password')
**print(password)**
print(request.data)
print(serializer.data)
user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
print(user)
return Response({'msg':'successful login'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

#### File *Serializer.py*

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password',]
        extra_kwargs={
            'password':{'write_only': True},
        }
```

#### File *Models.py*

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, number, name, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not number:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            number = number,
            name = name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, number, name, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            number = number,
            password = password,
            name = name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    number=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','number']

    def __str__(self):
         return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

#### Output

Quit the server with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>.

```
**None**
{'email': 'g@gmail.com', 'password': '123'}
{'email': 'g@gmail.com'}
**None**
\[06/Feb/2023 18:53:52\] "POST /api/user/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26**your text**
```

Comment: Please [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75362012/edit) the indentation for *views.py*. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
email=serializer.data['email']
password=serializer.data['password']
```

Comment: email value are print but password print None.

Comment: why print(serializer.data) => None

Comment: because drf does not include password in serialized and password is case sensitive